# Import postgis layer from S3 link

Tags: postgis, postgresql, import, amazon-s3

I have a postgis layer (`layer.sql`), which I am trying to add to my postgres database (`mydatabase`). The postgis layer is stored on S3 (`https://s3.us.../layer.sql`). I can add the layer to my database when it is stored on my local machine using `psql mydatabase < ~/layer.sql` but I'm failing to add the layer to my database, if I'm using the url. I tried `psql mydatabase < https://s3.us.../layer.sql`, which returns `-bash: https://s3.us.../layer.sql: No such file or directory`. Is there a different way command I can use when trying to add the layer with a url?